# Polynomial inversion in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm asked to compute the inverse of a polynomial  $P=a+b_1X+\cdots+b_nX^n$ in a ring $A=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X]$. It is known that $P$ is a unit when $a$ is a unit and the $b_i$'s are nilpotent. The nilpotents form the  ideal $b\mathbb{Z}$ where $b$ is the product of the prime divisors of $n$, so the $b_i$'s are multiples of $b$.

Then write $(P-a)=b(\sum c_iX^i)=bQ$, which is nilpotent, and let  $m$ be minimal such that $(P-a)^m=0$. We then can compute the inverse of $P$ from there: $(P-a)^{m}=0$ gives $P(P^{m-1}+\cdots+d)=(-a)^{m+1}$.

This gives an algorithm to find the inverse.

However, playing (a lot) with my CAS, it seems that there exists some $r$ such that $P^r=1$ so $P^{r-1}$ is the inverse. Is this true? The unit multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}[X])^{\times}$ is infinte but a unit generates a cyclic subgroup of order $<n$?

What I looked at: since we have the form $P^k=a^k+bR$, then if such an $r$ exists, it is a multiple of the multiplicative order $o(a)$ of $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, as one needs $a^r=1$. What is not clear is when  the coefficients of $R$ should be  zero or zero divisors with $b$.  The numbers $m\leqslant n$ such that $bm=0$ are in $\frac nb \mathbb{Z}$.

Can I get any help on this one?

Two examples:

For $n=48=2^4\cdot 3$, the nilpotents are $N(A)=6\mathbb{Z}$, nilpotence index of $6$  is $n(6)=4$. The polynomial $P=6X^{2}+6X+5$ is invertible. The multiplicative order of $a=5$  is $o(5)=4$. Then computing the $P^k$'s with $k$ a multiple of $o(a)$, one finds $P^{1\cdot 4}\neq 1$ but $P^{2\cdot 4}=1$ so $P^{7}$ is an inverse. The algorithm is quick to write, more than  the previous.

For $n=9$, the nilpotents are $N(A)=3\mathbb{Z}$, nilpotence index of $6$  is $n(6)=2$. The polynomial $P=3X^{2}+2$ is invertible. The multiplicative order of $a=2$  is $o(2)=6$. Then computing the $P^k$'s with $k$ a multiple of $o(a)$, one finds that  $P^{1\cdot 6}=1$.

Comment: I meant a $b_i$ is some nilpotent, a multiple of $b=\mathrm{rad}(n)$, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will always be an integer $r$ such that $P^r=1$.

Let $m$ be an integer such that $b^m=0$.  Then all powers of $P$ will be polynomials of degree smaller than $mn$.  Indeed, the coefficient in front of a term in degree at least $mn$ will be made of products of at least $m$ of the $b_i$'s, which are all multiples of $b$.  Thus the coefficient will be zero.

Once we know this, and since there is only a finite number of polynomials of degree at most $mn$, then we know that there is only a finite number of polynomials that are powers of $P$.  Thus there must exist two integers $0<u<v$ such that $P^u = P^v$.  Since $P$ is invertible, this gives us $P^{v-u}=1$.

Comment: Very clear. At least, this method gives a quick way to find the inverse. Merci.